# In Linux Centos 7, what is network.service and what does it do?

Tags: centos, networking, systemd

When I do `systemctl status network` I see its status as failed, but it can still request external URLs. Can someone explain, what does this service do exactly? Is it an interface for physical connections?

Answer (score 4):

#### Background

First off, this is not technically `network.service`, but rather `network.target`. Notice when we look for either of these files on a CentOS 7 box that we only find the `network.target` file.

```
$ locate network.service
$

$ locate network.target
/usr/lib/systemd/system/network.target
$
```

You can get systemd unit file descriptions directly from systemd via the `systemctl` command. For eg:

```
$ systemctl show network | grep -i description
Description=LSB: Bring up/down networking
```

If you look at the output of `systemctl status ...` notice this description shows up there:

```
$ systemctl status network
● network.service - LSB: Bring up/down networking
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/network; bad; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2018-09-03 21:49:05 EDT; 2 days ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 809 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/network start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Warning: Journal has been rotated since unit was started. Log output is incomplete or unavailable.
```

Also notice that there's a reference to documentation in the form of a man page.

*`man systemd-sysv-generator`*

> ```
>   systemd-sysv-generator is a generator that creates wrapper .service units for 
>   SysV init[1] scripts in /etc/init.d/* at boot and when configuration of the 
>   system manager is reloaded. This will allow systemd(1) to support them 
>   similarly to native units.
>
>   LSB headers[2] in SysV init scripts are interpreted, and the ordering specified 
>   in the header is turned into dependencies between the generated unit and other 
>   units. LSB facilities "$remote_fs", "$network", "$named", "$portmap", "$time" 
>   are supported and will be turned into dependencies on specific native systemd 
>   targets. See systemd.special(5) for more details.
>
>   SysV runlevels have corresponding systemd targets (runlevelX.target). Wrapper 
>   unit that is generated will be wanted by those targets which correspond to 
>   runlevels for which the script is enabled.
>
>   systemd does not supports SysV scripts as part of early boot, so all wrapper 
>   units are ordered after basic.target.
>
>   systemd-sysv-generator implements systemd.generator(7).
> ```

`systemd-sysv-generator` constructs targets & services based on existing SysV init scripts. In this case the init script that systemd is "wrapping" is this file - `/etc/rc.d/init.d/network`.

#### Purpose

In terms of what this unit file does, it's what brings up the network interfaces which are specified under `/etc/sysconfig/network`. This is a previously used directory that most of hte Red Hat based distros used before NetworkManager and systemd existed.

Systemd is bringing up any network interfaces defined in this directory as a way to stay backward compatible with how previous versions of Red Hat (CentOS, Fedora, & RHEL) behaved.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep desc -A 1 /etc/rc.d/init.d/network
# description: Activates/Deactivates all network interfaces configured to \
#               start at boot time.
```

DHCP etc